# Filenet migrating active workflows

Tags: filenet, filenet-process-engine, ibm-case-manager

We are planning to migrate from Filenet 4.5 to 5.2, question is can we migrate active workflows(workflows which are in middle of the process)to Filenet 5.2 case manager.

If yes can I get the steps or any documents or any referral links to do it.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I am replying very late, but this can help anyone having similar requirement.

There is no direct solution for achieving this. This is not a constraint from architecture point of view (whether PE is embedded into FN or not), but even in lower versions, migrating active workflows was never easy.

We were also in a situation where we had to migrate the active workflows. That time, we had to write our custom code, to read the data from old PE's tables one by one capturing the required metadata and launch a new workitem in upgraded PE. It was made clear to the users that the active items will need to be reprocessed. We just preserved the work items and relaunched them into the new system.

**Note: There are many drawbacks for this approach:**

1) Lot of rework is involved for the end user as they have to reprocess all the work items.

2) There wont be correct history for the work items. (if a work item was moved back due to a rejection in process, in upgraded system the item will show smooth flow (without rejection) of the work item, unless users actually recreate the earlier sequence of actions)

3) If there are any events triggered during the process, you have handle old actions.

4) If there are any DBExecute steps during the process, the database needs to be handled appropriately.